# Cómo usar Retrofit para llamar un servicio via VPN

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Estoy tratando de hace una llamada a un servicio REST con retrofit via VPN.

Para ello me conecto a la VPN a traves de mi PC y corro en el emulador la app pero me muestra este error al conectar.

> Failed to connect to /100.100.100.100:8080

¿Existe alguna forma de configurar los paramatros de la VPN en Retrofit?

Gracias

Este es mi código.

```
private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()


private var retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
```

Comment: Considero importante comentar que error es el que se muestra en el LogCat.

Comment: Claro, solo es un 'Failed to connect to /100.100.100.100:8080'

Comment: ups ! que "baseUrl" estas usando?